How to calculate next's month date without knowing the client's timezone?
Dates are really weird, and I can't seem to solve this issue:
Client lives in GMT+2 time zone and server saves everything in UTC time zone.
Client provides date 2024-12-01 which is converted to UTC time 2024-11-30T22:00:00.000Z and saved in the server.
Then client needs to get a date from the server that is one month after the saved date, which should be 2025-01-01. However, the server will return to client: 2024-12-31
Because server saved date is going to be the last day of the month but not the first as client provided. So, the following function does not work:


const setToNextMonth = (date) => {
  date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1)
}

// Correct
const clientDate = new Date('2024-12-01')
setToNextMonth(clientDate)
console.log(clientDate, '- Should return')

// Incorrect
const serverDate = new Date('2024-11-30T22:00:00.000Z')
setToNextMonth(serverDate)
console.log(serverDate, '- Actual return') 



The question is how to get the correct next month date without knowing client timezone?

2024-01-01(2024-12-31T22:00:00.000Z)? What format is: yyyy-mm=dd(yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss. sssZ)?

My bad, I've updated description. First is formatted date according to client time zone and in the brackets I've provided server response.

"…server will take November (30) month days instead of December (31)". Not exactly, it just adds 1 to the month number, so 30 Nov becomes 30 Dec. You want to treat a date as just the date part, without time, i.e. independent of timezone. The new Temporal object will let you do that. In the meantime consider passing date strings, treating them as local everywhere, making them timezone independent. "2024-12-01" should be parsed as local, but the ECMA-262 authors thought differently (which I consider a bug in the specification but it will be obviated by Temporal when it's introduced).

Store dates without timezone as dates without timezone, not as JavaScript date.

What if storing the date as string is not an option? For example MongoDB strongly encourages using only native data type.

Strings ("2024-11-18") and numbers (20241118) are native data types and trivially sortable. What database doesn't support strings or numbers, but does support dates?

Your issue is when the day does not exist in the next month. You said you want the last of next month if current day is larger than the number of days in next month.
I  normalise on 15:00 to not run into DSL and timezone issues since the largest TZ difference is 13 hours.


const getNextMonthDate = (dateStringUTC) => {
  const date = new Date(dateStringUTC);
  const savedDays = date.getUTCDate(); // Days of the passed month
  const time = dateStringUTC.split('T')[1]; // Extract the time part

  // Normalize to 15:00 UTC to handle DSL and TZ
  date.setUTCHours(15, 0, 0, 0); 

  // Add one month 
  date.setUTCMonth(date.getUTCMonth() + 1);

  // If saved days are greater than 28 and the our new date < saved days we overshot the date

  if (savedDays > 28 && date.getUTCDate() < savedDays) {
    // Adjust to the last day of the next month
    const lastDayOfNextMonth = new Date(
      date.getUTCFullYear(), // No issue with year transitions
      date.getUTCMonth(),    // Month is already the next month
      0,                     // 0th day gives the last day of the month we are aiming for
      15, 0, 0, 0            // Set time to 15:00 for consistency
    ).getUTCDate();

    // Roll back the month
    date.setUTCMonth(date.getUTCMonth() - 1);
    // Set the date to the last day of the month
    date.setUTCDate(lastDayOfNextMonth);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, set the date to the saved days
    date.setUTCDate(savedDays);
  }
  // Return the final ISO string with the preserved time
  return `${date.toISOString().split('T')[0]}T${time};`
};



const inputDate = "2024-11-30T22:00:00.000Z";
console.log(getNextMonthDate(inputDate)); // Expected: 2024-12-30T22:00:00.000Z;

const inputDate1 = "2024-01-30T22:00:00.000Z";
console.log(getNextMonthDate(inputDate1)); // Feb 28 or 29 depending on leap




I need the date that would be one month later than provided date. I've also thought about normalizing the hour but wasn't sure if this a good way to do regarding time zones. Also, why setting to 15:00:00 and not to 12:00:00?

I don't think this fixes the OP's issue, which is that the server sees the UTC date but the client sees the local date. They need a way to treat dates as plain dates, not as date and time or UTC offsets so they can do date arithmetic consistently (again, always ignoring time). One way is to pass date strings with no time part and treat them as local dates everywhere, always ignoring the time part and only ever passing back date strings. Easy if ECMAScript parsed YYYY-MM-DD as local (per ISO-8601) but it doesn't. Even easier if there was a toPlainDateString that produced local YYYY-MM-DD. :-)

@MCTG—because the largest +ve offset is 13 hours, so setting to 12:00 could still represent a different date. The largest -ve offset is 10 hours, so 12:00 works there.

@MCTG So what do you expect to see when you are on the 30th of Jan? The 1st or 2nd of March or the 28th or 29th of Feb?

@RobG you meant "so 15:00 works there" :)

@mplungjan This is not directly related to the question, but I expect to see the same or the last day of the next month. I solved it by checking if the difference between the provided date and the new date's months is greater than expected. In my case, if the difference is greater than 1, I use the function setDate(0) to set the date to the last day of the previous month.

@MCTG Ok, I changed my script to reflect your comments and question update
